# Gradle on Travis "no suitable constructor found"

Tags: java, gradle, travis-ci

I'm trying to test my project with Travis, and it is proving a fair challenge to do. Right now I'm up against [this strange error](https://travis-ci.org/JJ-Atkinson/splix-controller-ppcg/builds/199792543#L165):

```
/home/travis/build/JJ-Atkinson/splix-controller-
ppcg/src/main/java/com/nmerrill/kothcomm/ui/gui/TournamentPane.java:62: error: no suitable constructor found for Tab(String,CAP#1)
        Tab tab = new Tab("Game "+games.getTabs().size(),gamePane.apply(game));
                  ^
    constructor Tab.Tab() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor Tab.Tab(String) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Pane from capture of ? extends Pane
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

This is the code:

```
// gamePane = Function<U, ? extends Pane>
U game = tournamentRunner.createGame();
game.start();
Tab tab = new Tab("Game "+games.getTabs().size(), gamePane.apply(game));
```

This is a valid constructor, as the code compiles fine on my machine, but something is up with the travis build.

#### [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/JJ-Atkinson/splix-controller-ppcg/blob/master/.travis.yml)

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

script: ./gradlew check
```

Full file of `TournamentPane` is [here](https://github.com/JJ-Atkinson/splix-controller-ppcg/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nmerrill/kothcomm/ui/gui/TournamentPane.java#L62).

Comment: If you compare the [old API](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/) with the [new one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#constructor.summary) you can see that `Tab` did not have a constructor with two parameters before. Can you somehow verify which version of JavaFX is available in your Travis environment?

Comment: Ya know, I bet that's the problem. Duh... I'm not sure how to check the javafx version or change it though. Time to find out I guess. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636754/can-you-specify-minor-jdk-version-for-travis-ci

Comment: Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by an old version of JavaFX on the Travis build system.

The [old API](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/) did not include a constructor of the `Tab`class with two parameters; the [new one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#constructor.summary) that you want to use does.

Until Travis upgrades to the current minor JDK version you will have to manually add it to your infrastructure. Have a look at the post "[Can you specify minor jdk version for travis ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636754/can-you-specify-minor-jdk-version-for-travis-ci)" for instructions. As the apt repositories used by the Travis infrastructure are often quite outdated (I am however not sure about the specific container you use), I suggest using *linuxbrew*.